# Ajax call doesn't pass string to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to pass a string to an `IActionResult` function in an asp.net core 3.1 controller.

Ajax:

```
 $(function () {
        $('#ddlUsers').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUserInfoPartial", "UserInfo")',
                method: 'POST',
                data: { userId: 'test' },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'html'
            }).done(function (r) {
                $('#partialID').html(r);
            });
        });
    });
```

C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetUserInfoPartial(string userId)
{         
     return PartialView("_UserPartial", userId);
}
```

Breakpoints in `GetUserInfoPartial` are hit, but userId is always null.
What am I missing?

Comment: May want to review your Request and Response in Network Console. Maybe you are sending `NULL`

Comment: The request payload is "userId=test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to remove 'application/json', but it is sometimes tricky, depends on net version

```
         $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUserInfoPartial", "UserInfo")',
                method: 'POST',
                data:  { userId: 'test' },
                success: function (r) {
                $('#partialID').html(r);
            });
```

If you are not lucky there are  another 2 ways

easy way - to use Get instead of Post

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUserInfoPartial", "UserInfo")'+'test',
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (r) {
                $('#partialID').html(r);
            });
```

action

```
[HttpGet("{userId}")]
public IActionResult GetUserInfoPartial(string userId)
```

and harder one, if you want to use 'application/json' content type

Create ViewModel

```
public  class ViewModel
{
 public string UserId {get; set;}
}
```

ajax

```
          $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUserInfoPartial", "UserInfo")',
                method: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify( { userId: 'test' }),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (r) {
                $('#partialID').html(r);
            });
```

action

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetUserInfoPartial([FromBody] ViewModel model)
{      
      return PartialView("_UserPartial", model.UserId);
}
```

Comment: Changing to GET solved my issue.

Why didn't it like POST?

Comment: you can use a post from my first suggestion, but it is a form content type and  sometimes you need to add [fromform]. You are trying to use applicaion/json for Post, but in this case you need to stringify json and use [frombody]. The problem is that JSON.stringify doesn't work properly on primitive types, so  you have to create a class. But If I have only one or too simple params I prefer to use Get as the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove 'application/json', and  dataType: 'html' then it will work properly.
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("GetUserInfoPartial", "UserInfo")',
method: 'POST',
data:  { userId: 'test' },
success: function (r) {
$('#partialID').html(r);
});